# Getting the Content of a Embed but only from the 2 Line. Discord.py

Tags: discord, discord.py

So im trying to make my Bot detect certain words from a Discord embed. But I want it to only get the content from the 2 Line. I tried to do this

```py
if "Bad word" in embed.description[1]:
```

and that doesn't work for me it just ignores it. Im happy if someone could help me.

Answer (score 0):

*I'm assuming that you've singled out the `embed` from `message.embeds` already*

If it's in the description and line breaks are used, to get the second line you could use:

```py
embed.description.split('\n')[1]:
```

However, if they aren't used and it's just an overlap you might have to search the entire description for a `"Bad word"`

```py
if "Bad word" in embed.description:
```

Comment: I forgot to thank you. It worked with the first code u posted. Thanks for your time.